# - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Trying to get a DateTime picker working for my application but whenever I load the page, it crashes with the error in the title.

Here's the page I want to put the datetime picker on

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery_calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        oneLine: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
        minDate: 0
    });
</script>
```

Am I missing something small or am I way off?

EDIT: **Heres the link I used**

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

EDIT: **Picture of directory**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct? `Scripts/jquery_calendar/jquery-ui.js` rather than this path `scripts/jquery_calendar/jquery-ui.js` look the first letter uppercase 'S'

Comment: @EleazarEnrique doesn't work with a small s

Comment: jQuery UI has a DatePicker widget, not DateTimePicker. There are third-party libraries that add this.

Comment: Can you share the content of jquery-ui.js? A link to download it and check the content.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique You really want him to paste the entire jQuery UI library?

Comment: @Barmar I mean, a link for downloading! Sorry!

Comment: May be the path to the script is wrong.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: @Barmar you're assuming the content is from jquery-ui.  I know the finalname is `jquery-ui.js` but we don't know if it is really the content from jquery site.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that if he has a script called jqiuery-ui.js, it's a copy of the  jQuery UI library (perhaps customized using the Download Builder).

Comment: The wars start assuming things like that hehe.  I'm kidding.  Let's see what @AnnaDoe says.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique see the edit

Comment: @AnnaDoe please, can you share a print screen of your project directory, to be sure you're using the right path of your scripts?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique I think you're right with the path names. How would reference these path names?

Comment: Are you missing `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>`?

Comment: I try to use this library and I get the same error, I guess this library is up to date

Answer (score -1):

To get this works fine, you have to link the following js and css.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.7.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95w8uvgo/

Comment: Didn't work, still getting: - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker

Comment: I´ve update my answer, I suggest you use an other library.

Comment: In this examole is missing the jQuery-UI css don´t forget include.